# How to get data of parent node in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am doing nesting in D3 and in a nested element, I need to reach data object on its parent.

Right now I am doing

```
d3.select(this).node().parentNode.__data__;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Isn't `d3.select(this).node()` exactly the same as `this`? I'd simply use `this.parentNode.__data__`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`d3.select(this).node()` is the same as just `this` in the context of a function passed to a D3 selection. You could rework it like this `d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()` and get the correct value back without having to use the ugly double-underscore property.

Comment: Alas, this is only feasible if the parent node has data attached. If you had an intermediate node between the two nodes with data (i.e., `<li data="parent"><ol><li data="child">` using entirely fictitious notation), you'd have to do `parentNode.parentNode`, negotiating the DOM instead of the data tree.

Answer (score 23):

The other method I'm familiar with is to use `.each()` on the parent, and then deal with children within the closure:

```
d3.selectAll('.parent').each(function(parentDatum) {
    d3.select(this).selectAll('.child').each(function(childDatum) {
        // do stuff with parentDatum and childDatum here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I found this post when I had exactly the same issue. My solution, was to change the selection to pass on the data that I will need in the child, which I think might be a valid approach if you can live with the data redundancy in the node.

```
[
  {
    title: "Google",
    link: "www.google.com",
    languagePath : "en,fr,it"
  },

  ...
]
```

To help explain, I've used this in the context of a table, with two columns. The first column has the `title` and the second column has an `a` for each of the `accept-language` items.

So I did a sub selections of the split of `languagePath` and for each `enter` call, I would create a `a` with the text being the language.

So at this point I also need the `link`, so that the `a` elements look like:

```
<a href="www.google.com/en">EN</a>
<a href="www.google.com/fr">FR</a>
```

But the `link` is not part of the data passed to this child, so when I did the selection instead of doing:

```
var langLinks = tableRow
     .append("td")
     .selectAll("span")
     .data(function(d) {
        return d.languagePath.split(",")
      })
```

I did

```
 var langLinks = tableRow
     .append("td")
     .selectAll("span")
     .data(function(d) {
        return d.languagePath.split(",").map(function(item) {
                 return {
                   lang : item,
                   link : d.link
               })
      })
```

And so, when I'm processing `data` on the `enter()` of this selection I do have the parent's data.

Hope this is a valid alternative for some of you, it did help me.