# How do I get parent's info from a child?

Tags: javascript, database, json, d3.js

I am making a visual representation of a SQL database and using Francois Zaninotto's [CodeFlower](https://github.com/fzaninotto/CodeFlower)(which is powered by D3.js) to do it.

My question is, how do I access the name variable of the clicked node's parent?
I realize that this question looks similar to [How to get data of parent node in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417340/how-to-get-data-of-parent-node-in-d3-js) but their answer seemed unclear for my purposes. I am relatively new to D3 also, so that might be why.

**My json code format:**

```
{"name":"CRS_LOG_LEVEL","children":[{"name":"CRS_LOG","children":[{"name":"LOG_DESC","size":7,"type":"column"},{"name":"LOG_ID","size":7,"type":"column"},{"name":"LOG_TMSTMP","size":7,"type":"column"},{"name":"LOG_LEVEL_NBR","size":7,"type":"column"},{"name":"LOG_EVENT_CD","size":7,"type":"column"}],"size":100,"type":"table"}],"size":100,"type":"root"}
```

**My mouse click event listener:**

```
CodeFlower.prototype.click = function(d) {
// Toggle children on click.
if (d.children) {  //This makes the node that has children collapse and grow in size.
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
} else {
    var schemaName;
    var tableName;
    var columnName;
    if(d.type==="column") //only check the parent information if type===column
    {
        columnName = d.name;
        //tableName = Parent's name
        //schemaName = Parent's Parent's name
    }
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
}
this.update();
};
```

^ The above code is my slightly modified version of Francois' CodeFlower.js on the GitHub project I referenced at the top of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed `CodeFlower.prototype.flatten` to add a parent reference to each node it would be simple to later walk the tree in the click event. This would be structurally similar to what D3 does in [tree.nodes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#wiki-nodes) but without the positioning logic.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. I just had to modify the `recurse` function so that it had `var Parent = node;` after the recurse function call and `v.parent = Parent;` after the reduce function call.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the job.

```
var JSON = {"name":"CRS_LOG_LEVEL","children":[{"name":"CRS_LOG","children":[{"name":"LOG_DESC","size":7,"type":"column"},{"name":"LOG_ID","size":7,"type":"column"},{"name":"LOG_TMSTMP","size":7,"type":"column"},{"name":"LOG_LEVEL_NBR","size":7,"type":"column"},{"name":"LOG_EVENT_CD","size":7,"type":"column"}],"size":100,"type":"table"}],"size":100,"type":"root"}

for (var i = 0; i<JSON.children.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j<JSON.children[i].children.length; j++) {
        var parentIndex = JSON.children[i].children.indexOf(d);
        if (parentIndex !== -1) {
           var parentName = JSON.children[i].children[parentIndex].name;
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `parentName` should contain the name that you where looking for.

Note that you should not include the first line of code (`var JSON`...) in your script, and that you should replace every appearance of JSON (in my script) with your data object.

Comment: It looks like it should work but run-time would be significantly longer if the json String were much longer(which it might be). A break; in the if statement could shorten it a bit. 
One thing is for sure, it is definitely a better solution then including the parent field in each one of the children. 
Is there a simple way, like a predefined D3 method or something, that I could get the parent and its information from the child?